# Installing WLAN driver

Tags: wireless

After 6 hours I've come close to give up on Ubuntu.

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop computer, but my WLAN won't work. Right now I've connected the computer with an ethernet cable. (the lady of the house hates that cable).

I have an Asus PCE-N53, which is compatible with Linux, I downloaded the driver but there is no executable file in the folder. Only a MAKEFILE.

Keep in mind I've had Ubuntu for 6 hours, I have no idea what I'm doing here.

After some help on Ubuntu Norway's facebook page, I tried this:

```
espen@ubuntu:~$ cd /home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326
espen@ubuntu:~/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326$ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools'
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.o
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c: In function ‘RtmpAsicSendCommandToMcu’:
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:558:4: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pci_read_config_word’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
include/linux/pci.h:794:19: note: expected ‘u16 *’ but argument is of type ‘ULONG *’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:564:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:564:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:578:4: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pci_read_config_word’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
include/linux/pci.h:794:19: note: expected ‘u16 *’ but argument is of type ‘ULONG *’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:587:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:587:4: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:42:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:43:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:62:46: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__devinitdata’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:87:17: error: ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:88:17: error: ‘rt2860_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:90:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:90:29: error: ‘rt2860_remove_one’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:294:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:465:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:73:1: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/espen/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

As you can see it did not work.
Of course I've tried the Additional Drivers program, it only had drivers for my Nvidia card, nothing else.

Anyone out there have any suggestions?

I was told to ./configure.. I have no idea what that means!

Comment: The first step is to clearly identify your wireless device. Please open a terminal and run and post the result of: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: This may help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/193319/missing-driver-asus-pce-n53-11n-n600-pci-e-adapter You may also try ubuntu 13.10 on a live cd to see if it natively support your device. If it is the case, I would suggest you to simply upgrade your version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your issue is known. The card is an Ralink RT5592. Its not a Linux issue, rather Ralink has not updated the drivers for this card since its release. These drivers work for the 2.6 kernel. you would need a patch to get them to build properly for the 3.8 kernel and above like we use today.

I have the same card. I bought it cause it advertised linux support. Yeah, Samsung lies on the box to get sales too. I had to fight them over a printer with advertised Linux support. Finally they have updated their drivers to be worth something. Yeah, it supported linux... for a little while. I've been checking over and over hoping for some opensource support, but its not making headway very quickly last time I checked.

I'm debating on using another card. Doubt anyone will ever learn from this considering Windows is the only OS most people like to support.

http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800pci