# Need help with installing driver for ASUS PCE-N53 11n N600 PCI-E Adapter

Tags: drivers, compiling, asus, ralink

I've been trying to get my ASUS PCE-N53 11n N600 PCI-E wireless network adapter to connect to my home network without success. `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` gives the following information on the wireless:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5592]
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RT5592 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1043:851a]
Kernel modules: wl
```

Searching the Internet tells me getting this network card to work is an ongoing issue. [Asus' own driver](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEN53/HelpDesk_Download/) only have support for the 2.6.x kernel, and there have been several posts later that attempts [to get the driver to work with later kernel versions](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203226&page=2). Amongst other [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/249636/800704) uses a solution that was used [to resolve the same problem in ArchLinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152960) using [this patch](http://gridlox.net/files/rt5592sta_fix_64bit.patch). I've tried patching the driver following the instructions provided, which seem to work without error, but when I try to run `make` and `make install` I still get the same error messages I've been getting from the beginning. (I believe they are the same anyways) I'm unfortunately unable to post the whole text from the run, but I identified the following error messages:

When running `make`:
`user@user-homePC:~/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326$ sudo su
root@user-homePC:/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326# make`

(...)

```
`/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPIoctlShow’:
```

`/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4896:85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4896:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 , size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, __TIME__ );`

(...)

`/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:6960:2: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  *(ULONG *)pData = ralinkrate[rate_index] * 500000;
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:308: recipe for target '/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Error 1
Makefile:1550: recipe for target '_module_/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic'
Makefile:381: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2`

Following error messages were recorded during `make install`:

`root@user-homePC:/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326# make install`

(...)

`install -m 644 -c rt5592sta.ko /lib/modules/4.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: klarte ikke å hente informasjon om 'rt5592sta.ko': Fila eller mappa finnes ikke
Makefile.6:294: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/Nedlastinger/Linux/DPO_GPL_RT5592STA_LinuxSTA_v2.6.0.0_20120326/os/linux'
Makefile:474: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2`

(For those who don't understand Norwegian, it essentially says it's unable to find and install the file 'rt5592sta.ko'.)

I have posted the full text from the compiling and running the script below. If anyone has an idea what might be causing the error, some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's an AUR package `rt5592sta_linux_patched-dkms` which was last updated in 2016 for kernel `4.7.1-1`. If you're on kernel `>=5` this will not work for you, and consider manually installing the patched driver from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/mareksuscak/asus-pce-n53-linux) - you will get B/G support (no N support) but it is better than nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am unfortunately unable to test your solution, as I no longer use this computer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question, ‘how can I get my ASUS PCE-N53 11n N600 PCI-E wireless network adapter to connect to my home network’, is that you probably cannot.

When we both Google your device, more precisely, 1814:5592, we see many trouble-filled threads involving exactly what you found; it won’t compile on a modern kernel, even with a few different patches.

The ancient and rusty file that Asus provides for kernel version 2.6 will never, ever compile on your modern 4.13 kernel.

The links you found for Arch Linux are all for kernel version 3.15 or so; that’s still a generation behind your 4.13.0-xx.

I am unaware of any driver at all that will work with kernel version 4.4 or later.

Finally, here is a reliable and useful link: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_PCE-N53

> Probable Linux driver  none

I regret that there is no better suggestion, aside from purchasing a different device.

Comment: That is regretful indeed. :-( On a side note, I fail to understand why it won't work. Why can't the existing driver be implemented in a newer kernel?

Comment: It probably could if Realtek were so inclined. You could email them and ask. Ubuntu themselves only work with manufacturers drivers. I and others who answer lots of wireless and networking questions are not developers; we work with what's publicly available.